# New cms page is redirecting to home page

Tags: magento-1.7

I am building a e-com store on magento 1.7.0.2. I have created a new cms page which is redirecting to store home page. Browser is not going to new csm page.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your admin panel of magento.

Goto

> System>Configuration>>Web> URL Option

and change

> Auto-redirect to Base URL

to

> No